# SQL Server API POST calls - error in using SP_OACreate

Tags: sql-server, ole-automation

I am trying to setup a simple POST procedure through API but have been stumped on the first step - creating an object. I am running this on SQL Server 2012 SP4-GDR

I have confirmed that the `OleAutomationEnabled` is TRUE.

I am using SSMS with a user that is a member of the sysadmin role and have given explicit permission to `sp_OACreate` to that user.  Something that has me baffled is that when looking at the properties for `master.sys.OACreate` there are no users or roles other than the explicit one I defined earlier.

Trying to create an object returns an integer other than zero meaning it failed but cannot find any information on the specific integer pointing to a solution.

This is my script and result to troubleshoot:

```
USE master

DECLARE @hr int
DECLARE @Object AS INT;

EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;

IF @Object = 0 
     SELECT 'sp_OACCreate success', @object
ELSE
     SELECT 'Error in sp_OACreate', @object AS [objectReturned], CONVERT(binary(4), @object) AS [Code]
END   -- 0 is success

EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Result:

```
(No column name)    objectReturned  Code
Error in sp_OACreate    16711422    0x00FEFEFE
```

Can someone point me into the right direction?

Comment: Opinion... Using OLE automation inside the SQL Server process is not the right direction: it contributes to resource leaks and service instability. Why Microsoft ever thought it was a good idea to add the sp_OA* methods to SQL Server is anybody's guess. They also aren't portable to SQL Server for Linux or Docker containers. Web integrations should be handled in external processes written in .NET, PowerShell, Python, or any other language of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion and I will definitely take it in consideration.  At the current time I don't have the opportunity or time to learn how to create something outside of sql to send data from the db to an API call.   If it is an option in MSSQL I would like to get it to work and deal with the rest if it pops up.

Comment: I think you should check `@hr` variable for success or failure. Also, there are literally billions of sp_oa examples on the web (and stackO)

Comment: Thanks siggermannen, that was the issue.  Please copy your comment in an answer so I can upvote it.  Of course the $object will not be zero...you want an object so it better not be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the `@hr` variable for success/failure (0 is success) of sp_OACreate calls, since `@Object` will actually contain the handle to the created object.

I often use the following gist to point to how to do things when you want to post some data from SQL Server: [Gist on how to use sp_OACreate for posting data](https://gist.github.com/jarrettmeyer/5990daf0db3b1f4fd759df6ed4099685)